# update_or_create in import feature

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-queryset

I am working on import data from external source in json format data. I am getting and saving data in Person model and I would like to update models that already exists, so I am using update_or_create method but during import I am getting an error:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: managment_person.person_id`.

`person_id` has to be unique.

model Person

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is function to import data for Person model:

```
    def get_persons(self):
        r = requests.get('https://path_to_data_in_json')
        for obj in r.json()['data']:
            person, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(person_id=obj['id'], code=obj['code'], name=obj['name'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs regarding [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create)

> The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database
> based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields
> passed in the defaults dictionary.

---

> ```
> obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
>     first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
>     defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
> )
> ```

You should edit your defaults accordingly